# Combinations between two lists

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, combinations

I edited the post. I am sorry, I thought that it would appear in the Mathematica section. This question is regarding to the mathematica software.

I would like to make all the possible combinations between two lists with some restrictions. For example, let's say that I have the following lists:

```
list1=Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {j, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

```
list2={a,b}
```

What I would like to get is a list that makes all the possible combinations between each sublist in list1 and each one in list2, if possible without the elements in list2 taking the same sublist in list1. The solution that I want is:

```
{{{0, 0, a}, {1, 0, b}}, {{0, 0, a}, {0, 1, b}}, {{0, 0, a}, {1, 1, b}}, {{1, 0, a}, {0, 0, b}}, {{1, 0, a}, {0, 1, b}}, {{1, 0, a}, {1, 1, b}}, {{0, 1, a}, {0, 0, b}}, {{0, 1, a}, {1, 0, b}}, {{0, 1, a}, {1, 1, b}}, {{1, 1, a}, {0, 0, b}}, {{1, 1, a}, {1, 0, b}}, {{1, 1, a}, {0, 1, b}}}
```

Is there an easy way of doing it?

I would like to do it for larger lists such as the following:

```
list1=Flatten[Table[{i, j, z}, {z, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}, {i, -2, 2}], 2]
```

> {{-2, -2, -2}, {-1, -2, -2}, {0, -2, -2}, {1, -2, -2}, {2, -2, -2},
>   {-2, -1, -2}, {-1, -1, -2}, {0, -1, -2}, {1, -1, -2}, {2, -1, -2},
>   {-2, 0, -2}, {-1, 0, -2}, {0, 0, -2}, {1, 0, -2}, {2, 0, -2}, {-2,  1,
>   -2}, {-1, 1, -2}, {0, 1, -2}, {1, 1, -2}, {2, 1, -2}, {-2,  2, -2}, {-1, 2, -2}, {0, 2, -2}, {1, 2, -2}, {2,  2, -2}, {-2, -2, -1}, {-1,
>   -2, -1}, {0, -2, -1}, {1, -2, -1}, {2, -2, -1}, {-2, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}, {0, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {2, -1, -1}, {-2, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}, {2,  0, -1}, {-2, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {0, 1,
>   -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {2, 1, -1}, {-2, 2, -1}, {-1, 2, -1}, {0, 2, -1}, {1, 2, -1}, {2, 2, -1}, {-2, -2, 0}, {-1, -2, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {1, -2, 0},
>   {2, -2, 0}, {-2, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {2, -1,
>   0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {-2, 1,
>   0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}, {-1, 2,
>   0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, -2, 1}, {-1, -2, 1}, {0, -2,
>   1}, {1, -2, 1}, {2, -2, 1}, {-2, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 1}, {1,
>   -1, 1}, {2, -1, 1}, {-2, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {-2, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {-2,
>   2, 1}, {-1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {-2, -2, 2}, {-1,
>   -2, 2}, {0, -2, 2}, {1, -2, 2}, {2, -2, 2}, {-2, -1, 2}, {-1, -1, 2}, {0, -1, 2}, {1, -1, 2}, {2, -1, 2}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2},
>   {1, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {-2, 1,2}, {-1, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}, {2,
>   1, 2}, {-2, 2, 2}, {-1, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}

```
list2={a,b,c,d}
```

so that the solutions looks like:

```
{{{-2, -2, -2, a}, {-1, -2, -2, b}, {0, -2, -2, c}, {2, -2, -2, d}},....., {{-2, -2, -2, a}, {-1, -1, -1, b}, {0, 0, 0, c}, {2, 2, 2, d}}
```

note that the following should not be in the list

```
{{-2, -2, -2, a},{-2, -2, -2, b},{-2, -2, -2, c},{-2, -2, -2, d}}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: TL;DR but this is a maths problem anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: You'll get a better reception at [Mathematica.SE] but please try to format your question better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- I am assuming that the specific order of the pairs of triplets is not important.
- Your `Table` construct will be shorter using `Tuples`.
- You can get pairs without duplication using `Subsets`.
- `Permutations` is used to get all orderings of subsets.
- `Join` and `Apply` (`@@`) are used to flatten one level of the nested list.
- `list2` is transformed with `List /@ {a, b}` into `{{a}, {b}}` for use in:
- The final step is to `Map` the `Function` `Join[#, list2, 2] &` onto these subsets.

All together:

```
list1 = Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]
list2 = List /@ {a, b};

Join[#, list2, 2] & /@ Join @@ Permutations /@ Subsets[list1, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 0, a}, {0, 1, b}}, {{0, 1, a}, {0, 0, b}}, {{0, 0, a}, {1, 0, b}},
>  {{1, 0, a}, {0, 0, b}}, {{0, 0, a}, {1, 1, b}}, {{1, 1, a}, {0, 0, b}},
>  {{0, 1, a}, {1, 0, b}}, {{1, 0, a}, {0, 1, b}}, {{0, 1, a}, {1, 1, b}},
>  {{1, 1, a}, {0, 1, b}}, {{1, 0, a}, {1, 1, b}}, {{1, 1, a}, {1, 0, b}}}
> ```

Comment: Hi Mr. Wizard. Thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted. The only drawback is that it is very time consuming. When I try a list2 of 4 elements it is taking more than one hour (it still did not finish) using all the memory of my computer. And I would like to perform it for more than 6 elements of list2 (list1 will always have 3 elements). The number of possible combinations is really large. But in any case, I really appreciate it as this is what I wanted.

Comment: @user3125577 You're welcome.  OK, looking at your second example it will be impossible to enumerate the set.  You would have `Binomial[5^3, 4]` = 9,691,375 subsets.  With each subset having 4! = 24 subsets that is a total of 232,593,000 combinations.  It's just too many unless you have a supercomputer.  If you describe what you intend to do with all these combinations I may be able to recommend an alternative.

Comment: Hi Mr. Wizars. Thank you very much for your help. I will try to explain my best. Starting from a number of atoms I am trying to define the coordinates for all the possible combinations to create a molecule. I wanted to consider a simple case with only some restrictions. Regarding to the coordenates, the atoms are separated 2 Amstrongs and the angle between a new atom and the rest will be either linear or at 90 (a square distribution). Later I would start imposing new restrictions such as symmetry and so on... I did not think that it would be computationally so expensive.

Comment: so the list1 was meant to describe all the coordenates (in the case that you wrote was only a plane with x,y and separated 1 unit) and list2 had all the atoms.For example:CO.I wanted to create the list1 coordenates and list2={c,o}.Then make all the combinations {{(x1,y1,atom1},{x2,y2,atom2}},....}.Afterward, I would eliminate the ones that are the same by symmetry and finally the ones that does not have the atoms nearby (in this case, in a square o 1 unit). Finally export them as single coordenates. My final goal was to have different .txt for each combination. Of course for 2 atoms is simple.

Comment: @user3125577 I encourage you to post this full problem description on the dedicated [Mathematica.SE] StackExchange site.  I don't have the time to explore this now but it sounds like an interesting yet approachable problem.

Comment: Hi Mr. Wizard. I will do as you suggest. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @user3125577 I notice that you have not yet opened an account on [Mathematica.SE] (at least not linked to this one).  I hope to see your question there soon. :-)